# Problemas con Python - sintaxis

Tags: python, printf

¿por qué me genera un error cuando se ingresa por input un valor diferente de Numeros? además ¿por qué no puedo colocar los "¿?" aun si están entre comillas?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has declarado el encoding? En la primera linea de tu codigo coloca lo siguente  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: Hola CARLOS LUIS, te saludo y te doy la 

bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar 

el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio 

y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

! Con respecto a la realización de 

preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas 

por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes 

respuestas, **es muy importante leer 

[ask]**, saludos!

Comment: Por favor coloca el código y mensajes de error como texto, no como imágenes. Las imagenes no pueden ser indexadas por motores de busqueda ni leidas por lectores de texto a voz para aquellas personas con discapacidad visual.

Answer (score 1):

1. Para Python 2.7 tienes que utilizar `raw_input()`
2. Agrega en la primer linea: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` y verifica que tu terminal, editor de texto o SDK tengas definido: UTF-8 como text encoding

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias, por su pronta respuesta, ya se pudo solucionar el problema.

una ultima cosa como se logra que el realizar la consulta muestre la informacion impresa sin () y sin comillas sino como texto normal, como si fuera una charla

Ejemplo

actualmente sale:
('Me alegro de conocerle,', 'Carlos')

como quiero que salga:

Me alegro de conocerle Carlos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Carlos, esta es la seccion de respuestas. Por favor,  edita la pregunta para añadir esta pregunta o formula una nueva..